# Api call thats being set using useState doesnt update in time to be set into a useRef hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-ref

The useRef doesnt have the updated userState it returns undefined.

```
func(){
useEffect(()=>{
  global.api.getProviderDoctorByID(user._id, user.default_org).then((res)=>{setUserState(res.data.data.data)})
},[])

const prevUserState=useRef(userState)

return(
  <Button onClick={ ()=>{console.log(prevUserState)}}>prevUserState</Button>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) takes as argument an initial value but it won't get updated, and `userState` initial value is undefined. you need to set the current property to `userState` after initialize your ref:

```
const prevUserState = useRef(null)
prevUserState.current = userState
```